# Write string with newline to a text file c++

Tags: c++, text-files

First I don't know if my question already asked but I searched a lot and didn't find a straight forward answer to this question yet.
I want to create a program to read a string which has newlines `\n` in it and write the contents back to a text file on SD card with `fprintf()` function. My compiler is `ARM_GCC` and I'm using a specific library which only has `fprintf()` and `fwrite()` to write a string, so I preferred to only use these functions, but If you think there is another way I would appreciate if you say so.
I can easily use this program to write a string to file:

```
void sd_open(string sd_value)
{
  printf("Writing to Sd card...");
  FILE* fd = fopen("/sd/numbers.txt", "w+");
  fprintf(fd, "%s",sd_value.c_str());
  fclose(fd);
  printf("writed this value to sd: %s\r\n", sd_value.c_str());
  printf("Done\n");
}
```

The problem is this code writes the values of `sd_value` to one line only, I thought about using a for loop to search for newline in string and write line by line to a file but I don't know how to implement that.
Thanks.

EDIT...
suppose that `sd_value` is something like this:

```
string sd_value="Hello\nWelcome\nBye"
```

which must be stored as the following to the text file:

```
Hello
Welcome
Bye
```

Actually, `sd_value` is not handling in my program and a user types a value in another application and I receive it as a string. I can tell the user to use \n in his text box to enter a newline but don't know how to treat it as a newline in my code.

Comment: So you mean that `sd_value` may already contain `'\n'` characters, and you wan't to store single lines for reach of these segements adding the `'\r'` character before each of the `'\n'`?

Comment: Given that, judging from your code, you seem to know how to add a <CR><LF> to a string printed to the console using `printf`, It baffles me a bit that you need to ask how to do the same thing when printing to a file using `fprintf` - HINT: The mechanism is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only want to print the same exact string to a text file but it prints only in one line no matter if my string contains "\n" and I don't know how to add <CR><LF> to `printf`. Can you help a little clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differences between operating system which symbol(s) is chosen for `EOL` (end-of-line), e. g.

- Windows: `\r\n`
- Linux:       `\n`
- MacOS:   `\r`

It means that if you have in you `sd_value` the `EOL` symbols from one operating system (e. g. MacOS) and you will use your command

```
fprintf(fd, "%s",sd_value.c_str());
```

in other operating system (e. g. Windows), it is possible that this `EOL` symbol will not be interpreted as `EOL` in the target operating system and your whole string will be written in a single line.

Comment: I think the problem is right there in my application text box when I use \r\n it treated as 4character, not `EOF`, how can I make my program to treat these 4characters as EOF and insert a new line?

Comment: You mean `EOL` (End Of Line), *not* `EOF` (End Of File).

Comment: @JesperJuhl - Yes, EOL, thank you, I'm going to correct it in my answer.

Comment: @MasoudRahimi - How did you get these `\r\n` control characters? - *Automatically* (by operating system) or *manually* (you inserted them yourself)?

Comment: @MarianD I get them manually, The user uses these characters as input.

Answer (score 1):

There are many easy ways to do what you want but I really need example how the input is taken (sd_value)
What you are saying means that string sd_value contains :HELLO WELCOME BYE ....
and never do a newline

## Answers if like what I thought :

Each time you read a string end it with

```
*sd_value += "\n";*
```

If you have a lot of lines to process, using `stringstream` could be more efficient.

```cpp
ostringstream lines;

lines << "Line 1" << endl;
lines << "Line 2" << endl;

cout << lines.str();   // .str() is a string
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is not important how I grab `sd_value`, it can be "Hello \n World" which must write "Hello" and "World" in 2 lines separately.

Comment: I added some more info to my topic.

Comment: #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
std::vector<std::string> strs;
boost::split(strs,sd_value, boost::is_any_of("\n "));
--------------
This will split string each \n found and added to the vector then you can make loop to print the vector in the file
try it and tell me

Comment: I think first I need to find "\n" in the string then write the characters before that to the file with fprintf then find for later "\n" and do the same thing until end of the file, but I cannot implement this algorithm because I don't know how to.